# Why does a list keep changing when it is supposed to remain the same ? (Hill Climbing)

Tags: python

I am trying to use hill climbing to do an equal partioning with the following list :

```
[0.65882887, 0.06027274, 0.37937644, 0.06747164, 0.65809827, 0.03881445,
 0.07219876, 0.38016139, 0.05596416, 0.80919586, 0.78206881, 0.41166766,
 0.06511818, 0.60047652, 0.66955029, 0.53140532, 0.57318565, 0.66038214,
 0.98447152, 0.44450527, 0.35804503, 0.48759695, 0.88029813, 0.41067726,
 0.46043122]
```

I have to create 5 parts of 5 values. My solution is a list of 5 lists (and each of these 5 lists contains 5 different elements).
My problem is that the list where the solution is keeps changing even when it should not (ie when the mutated solution is worst than the previous solution, I think the program still keeps the mutated solution even if it should not).

Here is my program.
I have a mutate function that creates a randomly modified solution.
Score function tells me how good is my solution. The lower the score is, the better is the solution.
Hill climbing function mutate a solution, check if the mutated solution is better than the previous solution. If it is, it should update the solution. If it is not, the previous solution should remain the same.

```
import random
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(9983)
#hill climbing ?
#chaque étudiant se retrouve avec 5 gateaux, on veut qu'au final ils en aient tous autant
cake_weights = [0.65882887, 0.06027274, 0.37937644, 0.06747164, 0.65809827, 0.03881445,
 0.07219876, 0.38016139, 0.05596416, 0.80919586, 0.78206881, 0.41166766,
 0.06511818, 0.60047652, 0.66955029, 0.53140532, 0.57318565, 0.66038214,
 0.98447152, 0.44450527, 0.35804503, 0.48759695, 0.88029813, 0.41067726,
 0.46043122]
def mutate(answer) :
  new_answer=answer.copy() 
  method = np.random.random()
  if method < 0.5 :
    student_to_change = np.random.randint(0,5) #index de 0 à 5 exclu
    index_to_change = np.random.randint(0,5) #index de 0 à 5 exclu
    student_to_change2 = np.random.randint(0,5)
    while student_to_change2 == student_to_change:
      student_to_change2 = np.random.randint(0,5)
      
    index_to_change2 = np.random.randint(0,5)

    will_change = new_answer[student_to_change][index_to_change]
    new_answer[student_to_change][index_to_change] = new_answer[student_to_change2][index_to_change2]
    new_answer[student_to_change2][index_to_change2] = will_change
  else :
    biggest = 0
    smallest = 100
    for i in range(len(new_answer)) :
      if np.sum(new_answer[i]) > biggest :
        biggest = np.sum(new_answer[i])
        index_max = i
      if np.sum(new_answer[i]) < smallest :
        smallest = np.sum(new_answer[i])
        index_min = i
    index_to_change = np.random.randint(0,5)
    index_to_change2 = np.random.randint(0,5)
    will_change = new_answer[index_min][index_to_change]
    new_answer[index_min][index_to_change] = new_answer[index_max][index_to_change2]
    new_answer[index_max][index_to_change2] = will_change

  return new_answer

def score(answer) :
  biggest = 0
  smallest = 20000
  for student in answer :
    if np.sum(student) > biggest :
      biggest = np.sum(student)
    if np.sum(student) < smallest :
      smallest = np.sum(student)
  return biggest - smallest


def hill_climbing(guess,n) : #problem is that best_answer changes even when there is no need to change it
  best_answer = guess.copy()
  best_score = score(best_answer)
  count = 0
  for i in range(n):
    new_answer = mutate(best_answer)
    new_score = score(new_answer)
    if new_score < best_score :
      count+=1 #When the new score is lower than best score, we add 1 to count to know how many changes should have been made
      best_score = new_score
      best_answer = new_answer
    if i%100 == 0 :
      print("TEST",count,best_answer) #when printing this several times, we see that with the same value for count we have different lists for best_answer, but it should be the same
  return best_answer

num_iterations = 10000
guess0 = [cake_weights[:5],cake_weights[5:10],cake_weights[10:15],cake_weights[15:20],cake_weights[20:]]
answer = hill_climbing(guess0,num_iterations)
print("final",answer)
print("final score",score(answer))
```

I have noticed that when I add

```
if count > 10 : return best_answer
```

I get a pretty decent solution because I stop the program before it starts to create wrong answers.

Comment: `best_answer = guess.copy()` This is likely the cause.  `.copy()` performs a _shallow copy_, meaning that a new outer list is created, but the **contents** of the list are still the original objects.

Comment: Hello thank you for your help. When I remove .copy(), which gives me this line of code : best_answer = guess   I still get the same problem. Did I make the change correctly ?

Comment: No, that is not correct, because that is not copying _anything_.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: `import copy`, `best_answer = copy.deepcopy(guess)`